# How to make a Ruby application to send money to specific users?

Tags: ruby, paypal

I'm a Ruby user, who is trying to make a Ruby application that allows me to pay to my friends. My friends have Paypal account individually (i.e. sungpahfriend@hello.com ). I have a particular amount of money that I have to pay to my friends. 
I have a business account. ( sungpah@hello.com ). 
But I can't find how I can pay to my friend.

Do I have to put my credit card information or just my email address and amount of money? Also where should I put my friend's email address?

I really want to know how to this effectively. I'm looking forward to getting a feedback!

Best

```
require 'paypal-sdk-rest'
    PayPal::SDK::Core::Config.load('config/paypal.yml',  ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development')
    PayPal::SDK.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)

    PayPal::SDK.logger.level = Logger::INFO


    PayPal::SDK.configure({
      :mode => "sandbox",
      :client_id => "xxx-xx",
      :client_secret => "xx-xx"
    })


    @payment = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment.new({
      :intent => "sale",
      :payer => {
        :payment_method => "credit_card",
        :funding_instruments => [{
          :credit_card => {
            :type => "visa",
            :number => "4567516310777851",
            :expire_month => "11",
            :expire_year => "2018",
            :cvv2 => "874",
            :first_name => "Joe",
            :last_name => "Shopper",
            :billing_address => {
              :line1 => "52 N Main ST",
              :city => "Johnstown",
              :state => "OH",
              :postal_code => "43210",
              :country_code => "US" }}}]},
      :transactions => [{
        :item_list => {
          :items => [{
            :name => "item",
            :sku => "item",
            :price => "1",
            :currency => "USD",
            :quantity => 1 }]},
        :amount => {
          :total => "1.00",
          :currency => "USD" },
        :description => "This is the payment transaction description." }]})

    # Create Payment and return the status(true or false)
    if @payment.create
      @payment.id     # Payment Id
    else
      @payment.error  # Error Hash
    end
```

[image]

Comment: If you need help during testing, I would be glad to help. My email address is in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good case for the [Payouts API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payouts), which is also supported by the [Ruby SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK).

To fund the payout with minimal fees, you'll want to have the payout amount already in your PayPal account or link to your bank account.